# Stateless mvc app is giving error when it deployed to Local SF

Tags: azure, .net-core, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-stateless

I have 2 app as like, one for Stateful WebApi with dotnet-core-2.0 and another is stateless mvc app with dotnet-core-2.0. The Mvc app calling webapi endpoint as reverse proxy and showing data at html page by view. I am using "windowsserver2016 with docker-x64" as OS and VS2017 IDE for development.

The stateless mvc app is not running locally and gave below error when I deployed both to local SF(node-1):

```
"'System.FM' reported Error for property 'State'.

Partition is below target replica or instance count.

fabric:/StaffTracker/Web1 1 1 a7662494-35ec-474b-9a69-192a8acee8f8

  InBuild _Node_0 132159797021958499

  (Showing 1 out of 1 instances. Total available instances: 0)"
```

Please see below the error screenshot. How can I run it locally for debugging purpose?

[image: local SF error]

Comment: It is highly likely that an exception occurs within your application preventing it from starting. If you have any logging inspect it, otherwise add logging.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for Replay.Should i setup a logging at mvc app?

Comment: Yes, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0). I suggest using [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#azure-application-insights-trace-logging)

Comment: Thanks @Peter.
stateful ASP.Net Core 2 template does not seem to working with SF.
I opened a ticker at Github as below
https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1591